# Link to title is showing up twice for items in moderator queue

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, flag-queue

Currently, when an item is expanded in the moderator queue, the title is shown twice:

[image]

Why is it in there twice?  I'd expect (and I could have sworn) that it only showed once until now.

Comment: It's a title so nice, they're showing it twice?

Comment: @Bart That a reference to the old Letterman joke: "New York, New York.  The town so nice, they named it twice"?

Comment: Either that or [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsi5lXxzByU). ;)

Comment: @casperOne - That phrase is older than Letterman's usage of it.

Comment: @ChrisF We are both dating ourselves. =)