# Why is the question's title repeated in the flagging review?

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

[image: screenshot]

When you expand a question to review it's flag, the title is repeated in the question's body.  Is there any purpose for this?  I feel this could be left out since the text and links are identical.

Comment: I was _really_ tempted to only have the image and "**[Why is the question's title repeated in the flagging review?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173661)**" for the question's body, but that would've been obnoxious.

Comment: FWIW, [we have the same problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169650/link-to-title-is-showing-up-twice-for-items-in-moderator-queue).

Comment: @Sam I wish the question's title were "How are you suppose to make a bootable usb with CENTOS if centos has 2 iso files instead of 1", and the same in the body + the image